# How fast is TensorFlow compared to self written neural nets?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, implementation

I made my first neural net in C++ without any libraries. It was a net to recognize numbers from the MNIST dataset. In a 784 - 784 - 10 net with sigmoid function and 5 epochs with every 60000 samples, it took about 2 hours to train. It was probably slow anyways, because I trained it on a laptop and I used classes for Neurons and Layers.

To be honest, I've never used TensorFlow, so I wanted to know how the performance of my net would be compared to the same in TensorFlow. Not too specific but just a rough approximation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I wanted to know how the performance of my net would be compared to the same in Tensor Flow. Not to specific but just a rough aproximation.

This is very hard to answer in specific terms because [benchmarking is very hard and is often wrong](http://dtrace.org/blogs/bmc/2018/09/28/the-relative-performance-of-c-and-rust/).

The main point of TensorFlow as I see it is to make it easier for you to use a GPU and further allows you to use a large supply of programs written in Python/JavaScript that still give C++ level performance.

> How fast is TensorFlow compared to self written neural nets?

This is answering the general question of using TensorFlow/PyTorch vs a custom solution, rather than your specific question of how much of a speed up you'd get.

There was a relatively recent MIT paper, [Differentiable Programming for Image Processing and Deep Learning in Halide](https://people.csail.mit.edu/tzumao/gradient_halide/) trying to discuss the performance vs flexibility vs time spent coding a solution of 3 different languages.

Specifically they compared a solution in their language Halide vs PyTorch vs CUDA.

> Consider the following example. A recent neural network-based
>   image processing approximation algorithm was built around a new
>   “bilateral slicing” layer based on the bilateral grid [Chen et al. 2007; Gharbi et al. 2017]. At the time it was published, neither PyTorch
>   nor TensorFlow was even capable of practically expressing this
>   computation. As a result, the authors had to define an entirely
>   new operator, written by hand in about 100 lines of CUDA for the
>   forward pass and 200 lines more for its manually-derived gradient
>   (Fig. 2, right). This was a sizeable programming task which took
>   significant time and expertise. While new operations—added in just
>   the last six months before the submission of this paper—now make
>   it possible to implement this operation in 42 lines of PyTorch, this
>   yields less than 1/3rd the performance on small inputs and runs
>   out of memory on realistically-sized images (Fig. 2, middle). The
>   challenge of efficiently deriving and computing gradients for custom
>   nodes remains a serious obstacle to deep learning.

So in general you'll probably get faster performance with TensorFlow/PyTorch than a custom C++ implementation, but for specific cases if you have CUDA knowledge on top of C++ then you will be able to write more performant programs.

Answer (score 3):

A lot. There are all these optimizations that we might not have thought of like combining layers, functions, etc. I am a pytorch guy though, its clean and doesn't get in your way like tensorflow does.